# How to gracefully shutdown a boost asio ssl client?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

The client does some `ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::async_read_some()`/`ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::async_write()` calls and at some point needs to exit, i.e. it needs to shutdown the connection.

Calling `ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::lowest_layer().close()` works, but (as it is expected) the server (a `openssl s_server -state ...` command) reports an error on closing the connection.

Looking at the API the right way seems to be to call `ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::async_shutdown()`.

Now there are basically 2 situation where a shutdown is needed:

1) Client is in the `async_read_some()` callback and reacts on a 'quit' command from the server. Calling from there `async_shutdown()` yields a 'short read' error in the shutdown callback.

This is surprising but after googling around this seems to be normal behaviour - one seem to have to check if it is a real error or not like this:

```
// const boost::system::error_code &ec
if (ec.category() == asio::error::get_ssl_category() &&
  ec.value() == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ)) {
  // -> not a real error, just a normal TLS shutdown
}
```

The TLS server seems to be happy, though - it reports:

```
DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

2) A `async_read_some()` is active - but a user decides to exit the client (e.g. via a command from stdin). When calling `async_shutdown()` from that context following happens:

- the `async_read_some()` callback is executed with a 'short read' error code - kind of expected now
- the `async_shutdown()` callback is executed with a **decryption failed or bad record mac** error code - this is unexpected

The server side does not report an error.

Thus my question how to properly shutdown a TLS client with boost asio.

Answer (score 10):

One way to resolve the 'decryption failed or bad record mac' error code from the 2nd context is:

a) from inside the stdin handler call:

```
ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::lowest_layer()::shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_receive)
```

b) this results in the `async_read_some()` callback getting executed with a 'short read' 'error' code

c) in that callback under that 'error' condition `async_shutdown()` is called:

```
// const boost::system::error_code &ec
if (ec.category() == asio::error::get_ssl_category() &&
    ec.value()    == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ)) {
  // -> not a real error:
  do_ssl_async_shutdown();
}
```

d) the `async_shutdown()` callback is executed with a 'short read' error code, from where we finally call:

```
ssl::stream::lowest_layer()::close()
```

These steps result in a connection shutdown without any weird error messages on the client or server side.

For example, when using `openssl s_server -state ...` as server it reports on sutdown:

```
SSL3 alert read:warning:close notify
DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

(the last line is because the command accepts new connections)

### Alternative

Instead of `lowest_layer()::shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_receive)` we can also call

```
ssl::stream<tcp_socket>::lowest_layer()::cancel()
```

to initiate a proper shutdown. It has the same effect, i.e. it yields the execution of the scheduled `async_read_some()` callback (but with `operation_aborted` error code). Thus, one can call `async_shutdown()` from there:

```
if (ec.value() == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
  cout << "(not really an error)\n";
  do_async_ssl_shutdown();
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with this solution: async_shutdown callback is called with the following error: "application data after close notify"

Comment: @КириллВолков sounds a lot like you're actually using websockets there. Websockets have their *own* `close` protocol