# boost asio ssl async_shutdown always finishes with an error?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I have a small ssl client that I've programmed in boost 1.55 asio, and I'm trying to figure out why `boost::asio::ssl::stream::async_shutdown()` always fails. The client is very similar (almost identical) to the ssl client examples in the boost documentation, in that it goes through an `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve()` -> `boost::asio::ssl::stream::async_connect()` -> `boost::asio::ssl::stream::async_handshake()` callback sequence. All of this works as expected and the `async_handshake()` callback gets an all-clear `boost::system::error_code`.

From the `async_handshake()` callback, I call `async_shutdown()` (I don't transfer any data - this object is more for testing the handshake):

```
void ClientCertificateFinder::handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    if ( !e )
    {
        m_socket.async_shutdown( boost::bind( &ClientCertificateFinder::handle_shutdown_after_success, 
            this, 
            boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
    }
    else
    {
        m_handler( e, IssuerNameList() );
    }
}
```

`handle_shutdown_after_success()` is then called, but always with an error? The error is value=2 in `asio.misc`, which is 'End of file'. I've tried this with a variety of ssl servers, and I always seem to get this `asio.misc` error. That this isn't an underlying openssl error suggests to me that I might be misusing asio in some way...?

Anyone know why this might be happening? I was under the impression that shutting down the connection with `async_shutdown()` was The Right Thing To Do, but I guess I could just call `boost::asio::ssl::stream.lowestlayer().close()` to close the socket out from under openssl if that's the expected way to do this (and indeed the asio ssl examples seem to indicate that this is the right way of shutting down).

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575315/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-a-boost-asio-ssl-client

Comment: I've seen that one, but it seems to be openssl-related - in particular, the error that they're receiving is category asio.ssl, not asio.misc.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For a cryptographically secure shutdown, both parties musts execute shutdown operations on the [`boost::asio::ssl::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html) by either invoking `shutdown()` or `async_shutdown()` and running the `io_service`.  If the operation completes with an `error_code` that does not have an [SSL category](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__get_ssl_category.html) and was not cancelled before part of the shutdown could occur, then the connection was securely shutdown and the underlying transport may be reused or closed.  Simply closing the lowest layer may make the session vulnerable to a [truncation attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Truncation_attack).

---

### The Protocol and Boost.Asio API

In the standardized [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) protocol and the non-standardized [SSLv3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101) protocol, a secure shutdown involves parties exchanging `close_notify` messages.  In terms of the Boost.Asio API, either party may initiate a shutdown by invoking `shutdown()` or `async_shutdown()`, causing a `close_notify` message to be sent to the other party, informing the recipient that the initiator will not send more messages on the SSL connection.  Per the specification, the recipient must respond with a `close_notify` message.  Boost.Asio does not automatically perform this behavior, and requires the recipient to explicitly invoke `shutdown()` or `async_shutdown()`.

The specification permits the initiator of the shutdown to close their read side of the connection before receiving the `close_notify` response.  This is used in cases where the application protocol does not wish to reuse the underlying protocol.  Unfortunately, Boost.Asio does not currently (1.56) provide direct support for this capability.  In Boost.Asio, the `shutdown()` operation is considered complete upon error or if the party has sent and received a `close_notify` message.  Once the operation has completed, the application may reuse the underlying protocol or close it.

### Scenarios and Error Codes

Once an SSL connection has been established, the following error codes occur during shutdown:

- One party initiates a shutdown and the remote party closes or has already closed the underlying transport without shutting down the protocol:

  - The initiator's `shutdown()` operation will fail with an SSL short read error.
- One party initiates a shutdown and waits for the remote party to shutdown the protocol:

  - The initiator's shutdown operation will complete with an error value of `boost::asio::error::eof`.
  - The remote party's `shutdown()` operation completes with success.
- One party initiates a shutdown then closes the underlying protocol without waiting for the remote party to shutdown the protocol:

  - The initiator's  `shutdown()` operation will be cancelled, resulting in an error of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  This is the result of a workaround noted in the details below.
  - The remote party's `shutdown()` operation completes with success.

These various scenarios are captured in detailed below.  Each scenario is illustrated with a swim-line like diagram, indicating what each party is doing at the exact same point in time.

#### *PartyA* invokes `shutdown()` after *PartyB* closes connection without negotiating shutdown.

In this scenario, *PartyB* violates the shutdown procedure by closing the underlying transport without first invoking `shutdown()` on the stream.  Once the underlying transport has been closed, the *PartyA* attempts to initiate a `shutdown()`.

```
 PartyA                              | PartyB
-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
 ssl_stream.handshake(...);          | ssl_stream.handshake(...);
 ...                                 | ssl_stream.lowest_layer().close();
 ssl_stream.shutdown();              |
```

*PartyA* will attempt to send a `close_notify` message, but the write to the underlying transport will fail with `boost::asio::error::eof`.  Boost.Asio will [explicitly map](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/4f11be2/include/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp#L199-L223) the underlying transport's `eof` error to an SSL short read error, as *PartyB* violated the SSL shutdown procedure.

```cpp
if ((error.category() == boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category())
     && (ERR_GET_REASON(error.value()) == SSL_R_SHORT_READ))
{
  // Remote peer failed to send a close_notify message.
}
```

#### *PartyA* invokes `shutdown()` then *PartyB* closes connection without negotiating shutdown.

In this scenario, *PartyA* initiates a shutdown.  However, while *PartyB* receives the `close_notify` message, *PartyB* violates the shutdown procedure by never explicitly responding with a `shutdown()` before closing the underlying transport.

```
 PartyA                              | PartyB
-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 ssl_stream.handshake(...);          | ssl_stream.handshake(...);
 ssl_stream.shutdown();              | ...
                                     | ssl_stream.lowest_layer().close();
```

As Boost.Asio's `shutdown()` operation is considered complete once a `close_notify` has been both sent and received or an error occurs, *PartyA* will send a `close_notify` then wait for a response.  *PartyB* closes the underlying transport without sending a `close_notify`, violating the SSL protocol.  *PartyA*'s read will fail with `boost::asio::error::eof`, and Boost.Asio will map it to an SSL short read error.

#### *PartyA* initiates `shutdown()` and waits for *PartyB* to respond with a `shutdown()`.

In this scenario, *PartyA* will initiate a shutdown and wait for *PartyB* to respond with a shutdown.

```
 PartyA                              | PartyB
-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
 ssl_stream.handshake(...);          | ssl_stream.handshake(...);
 ssl_stream.shutdown();              | ...
 ...                                 | ssl_stream.shutdown();
```

This is a fairly basic shutdown, where both parties send and receive a `close_notify` message.  Once the shutdown has been negotiated by both parties, the underlying transport may either be reused or closed.

- *PartyA*'s shutdown operation will complete with an error value of `boost::asio::error::eof`.
- *PartyB*'s shutdown operation will complete with success.

#### *PartyA* initiates `shutdown()` but does not wait for *PartyB* to responsd.

In this scenario, *PartyA* will initiate a shutdown and then immediately close the underlying transport once `close_notify` has been sent.  *PartyA* does not wait for *PartyB* to respond with a `close_notify` message.  This type of negotiated shutdown is allowed per the specification and fairly common amongst implementations.

As mentioned above, Boost.Asio does not directly support this type of shutdown.  Boost.Asio's `shutdown()` operation will wait for the remote peer to send its `close_notify`.  However, it is possible to implement a workaround while still upholding the specification.

```
 PartyA                              | PartyB
-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 ssl_stream.handshake(...);          | ssl_stream.handshake(...)
 ssl_stream.async_shutdown(...);     | ...
 const char buffer[] = "";           | ...
 async_write(ssl_stream, buffer,     | ...
  [](...) { ssl_stream.close(); })   | ...
 io_service.run();                   | ...
 ...                                 | ssl_stream.shutdown();
```

*PartyA* will initiate an asynchronous shutdown operation and then initiate an asynchronous write operation.  The buffer used for the write must be of a non-zero length (null character is used above); otherwise, Boost.Asio will optimize the write to a no-op.  When the `shutdown()` operation runs, it will send `close_notify` to *PartyB*, causing SSL to close the write side of *PartyA*'s SSL stream, and then asynchronously wait for *PartyB*'s `close_notify`.  However, as the write side of *PartyA*'s SSL stream has closed, the `async_write()` operation will fail with an SSL error indicating the protocol has been shutdown.

```cpp
if ((error.category() == boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category())
     && (SSL_R_PROTOCOL_IS_SHUTDOWN == ERR_GET_REASON(error.value())))
{
  ssl_stream.lowest_layer().close();
}
```

The failed `async_write()` operation will then explicitly close the underlying transport, causing the `async_shutdown()` operation that is waiting for *PartyB*'s `close_notify` to be cancelled.

- Although *PartyA* performed a shutdown procedure permitted by the SSL specification, the `shutdown()` operation was explicitly cancelled when underlying transport was closed.  Hence, the `shutdown()` operation's error code will have a value of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.
- *PartyB*'s shutdown operation will complete with success.

---

In summary, Boost.Asio's SSL shutdown operations are a bit tricky.  The inconstancies between the initiator and remote peer's error codes during proper shutdowns can make handling a bit awkward.  As a general rule, as long as the error code's category is not an SSL category, then the protocol was securely shutdown.

Comment: Excellent answer, and a reference for a future! Thank you!

Comment: After having spent tens of hours trying to figure out how to handle the graceful closure of ssl::stream objects, THIS finally gave me the answers I was looking for. Christopher should add a special section to the asio docs to clarify.

Comment: I have concerns about the example code, it is misleading because it passes the address of a 1-byte buffer located on the stack, to `async_write`. This can cause a crash if the function returns before `async_write` completes. Instead, this call should be used: `async_write(ssl_stream, boost::asio::null_buffers{},  [](...) { ssl_stream.close(); })`

Comment: @Vinnie Fair point. The diagrams were not intended to represent a stack, but more so to capture the order of events (if it was a stack, `io_service.run()` would keep the buffer alive).  I would argue that using `null_buffers` changes the desired condition of detecting when the local write side of the SSL stream has been shutdown (`SSL_write` fails with an a shutdown error), as [`ssl_stream.async_write_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_write_some.html) with `null_buffers` will be optimized into a no-op, never attempting `SSL_write`.

Comment: Seems like the `PartyA initiates shutdown() but does not wait for PartyB to responsd.` version does not fail the write operation, at least that's what the error_code the handler gets would suggest. It is `success`.

Comment: It seems shutdown can also fails with a "ssl::error::stream_truncated" (i.e. SSL_R_SHORT_READ) with the category boost::asio::ssl::error::detail::stream_category (instead of ssl_category) ?

Comment: 10 years later, and there is _still_ no documentation in the Boost docs on how to properly shut down an `ssl::stream`.

Comment: _Boost.Asio does not automatically perform this behavior, and requires the recipient to explicitly invoke shutdown() or async_shutdown()._ How does the recipient (PartyB), via the Asio API, detect that it received a `close_notify` message?