# I have no idea why did Boost Asio SSL handshake always fail?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio, handshake

I tried use Boost Asio and Openssl to post some json to a SSL server,my case was it sucks when the code execute handshake with the server,the error was
"handshake: certificate verify failed"
 and I have no idea even I have Googled and viewed a branch of relative web pages ,I didn't find the answer yet,the SSL client example seems didn't work for me,what wrong I have done?

my code is

```
#include "root_certificates.hpp"
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/error.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <istream>

int postsslserver()
{
    try
    {
        auto const host ="mydomain.com";
        auto const port = "https";
        auto const target ="/apps/postpage.html" ;
        retcode = 0;

        char mybuffer[80];

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

        pwmd5hashed = "mysecret";

        std::string jsondata ="\"Double\":12.0000001,";

        int version =11;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;

        // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
        ssl::context ctx{ ssl::context::sslv23_client };

        //20181021
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

        // This holds the root certificate used for verification
        //load_root_certificates(ctx);

        // Verify the remote server's certificate
        //ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
        ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver{ ioc };
        ssl::stream<tcp::socket> stream{ ioc, ctx };

        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream.native_handle(), host))
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec{ static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category() };
            throw boost::system::system_error{ ec };
        }

        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        boost::asio::connect(stream.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);// error always occured this line of code,the error hints was "handshake: certificate verify failed"

        // Set up an HTTP POST request message
        http::request<http::string_body> req{ http::verb::post, target, version };
        req.set(http::field::host, host);
        req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        req.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
        req.set(http::field::body, jsondata);
        //req.keep_alive(req.keep_alive());

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::write(stream, req);

        // This buffer is used for reading and must be persisted
        boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

        // Declare a container to hold the response
        http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::read(stream, buffer, res);

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res << std::endl;

        // Gracefully close the stream
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        stream.shutdown(ec);
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec.assign(0, ec.category());
        }
        if (ec)
            throw boost::system::system_error{ ec };

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        //std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        write_text_to_log_file(e.what());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What certificate does the server use? Try connecting with `openssl s_client` instead and debugging the certs that way

Comment: @sehe thanks for replying my question,the server use a https certificate which is NOT a self-signed

Comment: @sehe thanks your opinion ,I 'm gonna try openssl s_client

Comment: I found that it was a Let's encrypt certificate,the error was "unable to get local issuer certificate" ,thanks