# beast : http bad request

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

```
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::empty_body> req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;

public:
    explicit
    session(
        net::executor ex,
        ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(ex)
    , stream_(ex, ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        char const* target)
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host))
        {
            beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
            std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
            return;
        }

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        // req_.version(version);
        req_.method(http::verb::get);
        req_.target(target);
        req_.set(http::field::host, host);
        req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream_.async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::async_write(stream_, req_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_write(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res_ << std::endl;

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Gracefully close the stream
        stream_.async_shutdown(
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_shutdown,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_shutdown(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec == net::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec = {};
        }
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "shutdown");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    // The session is constructed with a strand to
    // ensure that handlers do not execute concurrently.
    std::make_shared<session>(
        net::make_strand(ioc),
        ctx
        )->run("api.binance.com", "443", "/api/v3/depth");

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

docs :
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#order-book

I am trying to get the order-book snapshot using http request, it seems that it is not working.

whats wrong here ?

Also, some other endpoints require api key configuration and i haven't found a single beast http client example that lets you do it.

advance thanks!

error :

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 95
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 22 Apr 2022 02:57:15 GMT
Server: nginx
x-mbx-uuid: 5a6a1b4b-b94a-48e1-bb29-d5e6e04dec2d
x-mbx-used-weight: 1
x-mbx-used-weight-1m: 1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 51e2dff3d89b89a15e6f1fb094173408.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: MAA51-P1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: dWVPcdXGgFqav6nvGdXVs_sBvP29t0QBS8r9VRkK8yx2ln2nX45uUg==

{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'symbol' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a plain HTTP request to a HTTPS service. There is nothing wrong per se with your code, and you can reproduce exactly the same answer using e.g. curl:

```
$ curl http://api.binance.com:443/api/v3/depth
```

You may take a look at some of the [beast examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/examples.html#beast.examples.clients) using SSL. As far as I remember, beast lets you exchange the underlying stream from a plain TCP socket to a SSL socket.

**Edit**
For the api key configuration, you must elaborate more exactly what is needed.

Also remember, that boost beast is a very generic and low level library. There are only the most basic examples in the documentation, because the library is meant for library developers primarly. While beast is imho a brilliant library, there might be other web client libraries, that are easier to use if you only need to make simple web requests.

Comment: i did same way you instructed, it shows error again!
i edited my question, please check it again

Comment: That's not the same error. This is not even really an error. You just did not adhere to the web api. Apparently you are supposed to send json data in the body of the request, that includes a parameter named "symbol"...