# boost.beast : HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio, boost-beast

```
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/executor.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::empty_body> req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;

public:
    explicit
    session(
        net::executor ex,
        ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(ex)
    , stream_(ex, ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        char const* target)
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host))
        {
            beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
            std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
            return;
        }

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        // req_.version(version);
        req_.method(http::verb::get);
        req_.target(target);
        req_.set(http::field::host, host);
        req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream_.async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::async_write(stream_, req_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_write(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res_ << std::endl;

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Gracefully close the stream
        stream_.async_shutdown(
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_shutdown,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_shutdown(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec == net::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec = {};
        }
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "shutdown");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    // The session is constructed with a strand to
    // ensure that handlers do not execute concurrently.
    std::make_shared<session>(
        net::make_strand(ioc),
        ctx
        )->run("api.binance.com", "443", "/api/v3/depth");

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

docs :
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#order-book

I am trying to get the order-book snapshot using http request, it seems that it is not working.

whats wrong here ?

Also, some other endpoints require api key configuration and i haven't found a single beast http client example that lets you do it.

advance thanks!

error :

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 95
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 15:13:18 GMT
Server: nginx
x-mbx-uuid: b9610be5-e450-4bb6-838b-116df22c8751
x-mbx-used-weight: 1
x-mbx-used-weight-1m: 1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-WebKit-CSP: default-src 'self'
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 82b2159ca009b3eb264d21b0a7d7a822.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: MAA51-P1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: SsG9F9Zv5ktdaSZpqcXvJ3_agCVhz2YfmQX3b84t8znE4xyTsHJBJQ==

{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'symbol' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}
shutdown: stream truncated
```

Comment: "Also, some other endpoints require api key configuration and i haven't found a single beast http client example that lets you do it." - probably look at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/decorator.html

Comment: thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#order-book) lists two parameters:

| Name | Type | Mandatory | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| symbol | STRING | YES |  |
| limit | INT | NO | Default 100; max 5000. If limit > 5000, then the response will truncate to 5000. |

You pass none of them:

```
GET /api/v3/depth HTTP/1.1
Host: api.binance.com
User-Agent: Boost.Beast/322
```

So add a body with the paramaters!

```
req_.body() = serialize(json::object {{"symbol", "btcusdt"}});
req_.prepare_payload(); // make HTTP 1.1 compliant
```

This assumes that you change `empty_body` to `string_body` for `req_`.

Sadly I couldn't test it momentarily because CloudFront is rejecting requests on all alternative endpoints at the moment.

### Listing For Comparison

(includes a type alias for `executor` to allow Boost 1.78)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http  = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net   = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl   = boost::asio::ssl;     // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
namespace json  = boost::json;
using tcp       = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

using executor = net::any_io_executor; // boost 1.78 compat, comment if not applicable

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(beast::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::string_body> req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;

public:
    explicit
    session(
        executor ex,
        ssl::context& ctx)
    : resolver_(ex)
    , stream_(ex, ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        char const* target)
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host))
        {
            beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
            std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
            return;
        }

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        // req_.version(version);
        req_.method(http::verb::get);
        req_.target(target);
        req_.set(http::field::host, host);
        req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        req_.body() = serialize(json::object {{"symbol", "btcusdt"}});
        req_.prepare_payload(); // make HTTP 1.1 compliant

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream_.async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        std::cout << "Sending " << req_ << std::endl;
        http::async_write(stream_, req_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_write(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        beast::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Write the message to standard out
        std::cout << res_ << std::endl;

        // Set a timeout on the operation
        beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

        // Gracefully close the stream
        stream_.async_shutdown(
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_shutdown,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_shutdown(beast::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec == net::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec = {};
        }
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "shutdown");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};

    // Verify the remote server's certificate
    ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Launch the asynchronous operation
    // The session is constructed with a strand to
    // ensure that handlers do not execute concurrently.
    std::make_shared<session>(
        net::make_strand(ioc),
        ctx
        )->run("api3.binance.com", "443", "/api/v3/depth");
    // see for endpoints: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-info

    // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
    // the get operation is complete.
    ioc.run();
}
```