boost beast async stackless coroutine HTTPS client throws: 167772451 - application data after close notify (SSL routines)
I'm trying to develop a quick HTTPS client using boost::beast (version 1.86) and stackless coroutines. I'm throwing up an HTTPS post to api.mailgun.net.
Everything works EXCEPT RIGHT AFTER the async_shutdown is called an SSL 167772451 - application data after close notify (SSL routines) is thrown.
I'm not sure why that is. The request_/response_ pointers should not be freed at this point and all of the reading should be completed in its entirety.
Below is the code. Again, it fails right after async_shutdown is called in the last function which is the biggest co-routine. Is this error "normal" and ignorable?
/**
* Do the session
*/
struct Session
{
    boost::asio::coroutine coroutine_;
    boost::shared_ptr<http_ssl_stream> stream_;
    boost::shared_ptr<RequestType> request_;
    uint timeout_;
    std::string host_;
    std::string port_;

    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver> resolver_;
    std::unique_ptr<ResponseType> response_;
    std::unique_ptr<BufferType> buffer_;

    /**
    * First call
    */
    template<typename Self>
    void operator()( Self &self )
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if( !SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_->native_handle(), host_.c_str()) )
        {
            // Callback with error
            return self.complete( boost::beast::error_code( static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category() ), boost::none );
        }


        // Resolve the resolve
        resolver_.reset( new boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver( stream_->get_executor() ) );


        // Resolve
        resolver_->async_resolve( host_, port_, std::move( self ) );
    }

    /**
    * On resolved call
    */
    template<typename Self>
    void operator()( Self &self, boost::beast::error_code error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type results )
    {
        // Resolve error, quit
        if( error )
        {
            return self.complete( error, boost::none );
        }


        // Set the expiration
        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

        // Do a connnect
        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).async_connect(
                    results,
                    std::move( self )
                );
    }

    /**
    * On connected
    */
    template<typename Self>
    void operator()( Self &self, boost::beast::error_code error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type results )
    {
        // Connect error
        if( error )
        {
            return self.complete( error, boost::none );
        }

        // Set the expiration
        boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

        // Do a handshake
        stream_->async_handshake(
                    boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                    std::move( self )
                );
    }

    /**
    * After handshake
    */
    template<typename Self>
    void operator()( Self &self, boost::beast::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_transferred=0 )
    {

        // Coroutine for easy state knowing
        BOOST_ASIO_CORO_REENTER( coroutine_ )
        {
            /*
            // Do the handshake
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD
            {
                // Connect error
                if( error )
                    return self.complete( error, boost::none );


                // Set the expiration
                boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

                // Do a handshake
                stream_->async_handshake(
                            boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                            std::move( self )
                        );
            }
            */

            // Do the write
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD
            {
                // Handshake error
                if( error )
                {
                    return self.complete( error, boost::none );
                }

                // Set up an HTTP GET request message
                request_->version( 11 );
                //request_->body() = body_;

                // Set the expiration
                boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

                // Write the request
                boost::beast::http::async_write( *stream_, *request_, std::move( self ) );
            }

            // Execute a read
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD
            {
                // Write error
                if( error )
                {
                    return self.complete( error, boost::none );
                }

                // Create the response
                response_.reset( new ResponseType );

                // Create the buffa
                buffer_.reset( new BufferType );

                // Set the expiration
                boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

                // Receive the HTTP response
                boost::beast::http::async_read( *stream_, *buffer_, *response_, std::move( self ) );
            }

            // Shutdown the socket
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD
            {
                // Read error
                if( error )
                {
                    return self.complete( error, boost::none );
                }


                // Set the expiration
                boost::beast::get_lowest_layer( *stream_ ).expires_after( std::chrono::seconds( timeout_ ) );

                // Receive the HTTP response
                stream_->async_shutdown( std::move( self ) );
            }

            // Shutdown error
            if( error == boost::asio::error::eof or error == boost::asio::ssl::error::stream_truncated )
            {

                // Rationale:
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
                error = {};
            }


            // Did we get it?
            if( error )
            {
                self.complete( error, boost::none );
                return;
            }

            // Return no error and the buffer
            self.complete( error, *response_ );
        }
    }

};



Please always make your example self contained. The code required to make this into working code was not trivial (see my async_https_get below). Also, I just noticed that std::move(self) may invoke UB in the call async_resolve(host_, port_, std::move(self)) because it depends on the order of argument evaluation. You should probably move the host/port to locals first.

Apologies on not making a self contained example. Appreciate the response and all the work you did.

I reproduced it on my end, with a GET to google.com. I get the stream_truncated error as expectable in the wild. You already deal with that:

Replacing www.google.com with api.mailgun.net just removes that symptom for me:

Can you compare your implementation and check back with your own tests?
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/url.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace beast       = boost::beast;
namespace http        = boost::beast::http;
namespace net         = boost::asio;
namespace ssl         = net::ssl;
using url             = boost::urls::url;
using tcp             = net::ip::tcp;
using http_ssl_stream = boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>;
using RequestType     = http::request<http::string_body>;
using ResponseType    = http::response<http::string_body>;
using BufferType      = boost::beast::flat_buffer;

/**
 * Do the session
 */
struct Session {
    net::coroutine                     coroutine_; // by value
    boost::shared_ptr<http_ssl_stream> stream_;
    boost::shared_ptr<RequestType>     request_;
    uint                               timeout_;     // by value
    std::string                        host_, port_; // ephemeral

    std::unique_ptr<tcp::resolver> resolver_ = {}; // stable
    std::unique_ptr<ResponseType>  response_ = {}; // stable
    std::unique_ptr<BufferType>    buffer_   = {}; // stable

    /**
     * First call
     */
    template <typename Self> void operator()(Self& self) {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << std::endl;
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_->native_handle(), host_.c_str())) {
            // Callback with error
            return self.complete(
                beast::error_code(static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()),
                boost::none);
        }

        resolver_ = std::make_unique<tcp::resolver>(stream_->get_executor());
        resolver_->async_resolve(host_, port_, std::move(self));
    }

    /**
     * On resolved call
     */
    template <typename Self>
    void operator()(Self& self, beast::error_code error, tcp::resolver::results_type results) {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
        // Resolve error, quit
        if (error) {
            return self.complete(error, boost::none);
        }

        // Set the expiration
        beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(timeout_));

        // Do a connnect
        beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).async_connect(results, std::move(self));
    }

    /**
     * On connected
     */
    template <typename Self>
    void operator()(Self& self, beast::error_code error,
                    tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type /*results*/) {
        std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
        // Connect error
        if (error) {
            return self.complete(error, boost::none);
        }

        // Set the expiration
        beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(timeout_));

        // Do a handshake
        stream_->async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, std::move(self));
    }

    /**
     * After handshake
     */
    template <typename Self>
    void operator()(Self& self, beast::error_code error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/ = 0) {
        // Coroutine for easy state knowing
        BOOST_ASIO_CORO_REENTER(coroutine_) {

            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            // Do the write
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD {
                // Handshake error
                if (error) {
                    return self.complete(error, boost::none);
                }

                // Set up an HTTP GET request message
                request_->version(11);
                // request_->body() = body_;

                // Set the expiration
                beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(timeout_));

                // Write the request
                http::async_write(*stream_, *request_, std::move(self));
            }

            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            // Execute a read
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD {
                // Write error
                if (error) {
                    return self.complete(error, boost::none);
                }

                // Create the response
                response_ = std::make_unique<ResponseType>();

                // Create the buffa
                buffer_ = std::make_unique<BufferType>();

                // Set the expiration
                beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(timeout_));

                // Receive the HTTP response
                http::async_read(*stream_, *buffer_, *response_, std::move(self));
            }

            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            // Shutdown the socket
            BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD {
                // Read error
                if (error) {
                    return self.complete(error, boost::none);
                }

                // Set the expiration
                beast::get_lowest_layer(*stream_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(timeout_));

                // Receive the HTTP response
                stream_->async_shutdown(std::move(self));
            }

            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            // Shutdown error
            if (error == net::error::eof or error == ssl::error::stream_truncated) {

                // Rationale:
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
                error = {};
            }

            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": " << error.message() << std::endl;
            // Did we get it?
            if (error) {
                self.complete(error, boost::none);
                return;
            }

            // Return no error and the buffer
            self.complete(error, std::move(*response_));
        }
    }
};

template <typename Executor, typename Token> auto async_https_get(Executor ex, url what, Token&& token) {
    static ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);

    std::string port     = what.has_port() ? what.port() : "https";
    std::string resource = what.encoded_resource().decode();
    std::cout << "Host: " << what.host() << " Port: " << port << " Resource: " << resource << std::endl;

    auto request = boost::make_shared<RequestType>(http::verb::get, resource, 11, "{}");
    request->set(http::field::host, what.host());

    Session session{
        net::coroutine(),
        boost::make_shared<http_ssl_stream>(ex, ctx),
        request,
        5, // seconds
        what.host(),
        port,
    };

    return net::async_compose<Token, void(beast::error_code, boost::optional<ResponseType>)>(
        std::move(session), token, ex);
}

int main() {
    net::thread_pool ioc(1);

    // url what("https://www.google.com/");
    url what("https://api.mailgun.net/");

    async_https_get(make_strand(ioc), what,
                    [&](beast::error_code ec, boost::optional<ResponseType> response) {
                        std::cout << "--\nCompleting with error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        if (!ec)
                            std::cout << "--\nResponse: " << response->base() << std::endl;
                    });

    ioc.join();
}


Note some changed details. Notably, return the response by move. That one might actually be a savings. I'd suggest grouping all the dynamically allocated resources in a single smart pointer for efficiency.
