# What is the proper way to securely disconnect an asio SSL socket?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio

A `boost-asio` SSL/TLS TCP socket is implemented as an `ssl::stream` over a `tcp::socket`:

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_socket;
```

In the [TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) protocol, a cryptographically secure shutdown involves parties exchanging `close_notify` messages. Simply closing the lowest layer may make the session vulnerable to a [truncation attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Truncation_attack).

In [boost asio ssl async_shutdown always finishes with an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error/25703699#25703699) @Tanner Sansbury describes the SSL shutdown process in detail with a number of scenarios and proposes using an `async_shutdown` followed by an `async_write` to disconnect an SSL stream prior to closing the socket:

```
ssl_socket.async_shutdown(...);
const char buffer[] = "";
async_write(ssl_socket, buffer, [](...) { ssl_socket.close(); })
```

Performing an `async_shutdown` on an `ssl::stream` sends an SSL `close_notify` message and waits for a response from the other end. The purpose of writing to the stream after the `async_shutdown` is to be notified when `async_shutdown` has sent the `close_notify` so that the socket can be closed without waiting for the response. However, in the current (1.59) version of [boost](http://www.boost.org/) the call to `async_write` fails...

In [How to gracefully shutdown a boost asio ssl client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575315/how-to-gracefully-shutdown-a-boost-asio-ssl-client) @maxschlepzig proposes shutting down receiver of the underlying TCP socket:

```
ssl_socket.lowest_layer()::shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_receive);
```

This produces a `short read` error, and `async_shutdown` is called when it's detected in the error handler:

```
// const boost::system::error_code &ec
if (ec.category() == asio::error::get_ssl_category() &&
  ec.value()    == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ))
{
  // -> not a real error:
  do_ssl_async_shutdown();
}
```

Or cancelling the read/write operations on the socket and then calling SSL async shutdown, i.e.:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
ssl_socket.cancel(ec);
ssl_socket.async_shutdown([](...) { ssl_socket.close(); };
```

I'm currently using this last method since it works with the current version of `boost`.

What is the correct/best way to securely disconnect a `boost-asio` SSL socket?

Comment: It depends. If you've received a `close_notify` you aren't obliged to send one.

Comment: Yes you are, but you are not required to wait to receive a `close_notify` after you have sent one.

Answer (score 8):

To securely disconnect, perform a shutdown operation and then close the underlying transport once shutdown has complete.  Hence, the method you are currently using will perform a secure disconnect:

```cpp
boost::system::error_code ec;
ssl_socket.cancel(ec);
ssl_socket.async_shutdown([](...) { ssl_socket.close(); };
```

Be aware that the current `async_shutdown` operation will be considered complete when either:

- A `close_notify` has been received by the remote peer.
- The remote peer closes the socket.
- The operation has been cancelled.

Hence, if resources are bound to the lifetime of the socket or connection, then these resources will remain alive waiting for the remote peer to take action or until the operation is cancelled locally.  However, waiting for a `close_notify` response is not required for a secure shutdown.  If resources are bound to the connection, and locally the connection is considered dead upon sending a shutdown, then it may be worthwhile to not wait for the remote peer to take action:

```cpp
ssl_socket.async_shutdown(...);
const char buffer[] = "";
async_write(ssl_socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer),
    [](...) { ssl_socket.close(); })
```

When a client sends a `close_notify` message, the client guarantees that the client will not send additional data across the secure connection.  In essence, the `async_write()` is being used to detect when the client has sent a `close_notify`, and within the completion handler, will close the underlying transport, causing the `async_shutdown()` to complete with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  As noted in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703699/1053968), the `async_write()` operation is expected to fail.

> ... as the write side of *PartyA*'s SSL stream has closed, the `async_write()` operation will fail with an SSL error indicating the protocol has been shutdown.
>
> ```cpp
> if ((error.category() == boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category())
>      && (SSL_R_PROTOCOL_IS_SHUTDOWN == ERR_GET_REASON(error.value())))
> {
>   ssl_stream.lowest_layer().close();
> }
> ```
>
> The failed `async_write()` operation will then explicitly close the underlying transport, causing the `async_shutdown()` operation that is waiting for *PartyB*'s `close_notify` to be cancelled.

Comment: Thank you @Tanner, I totally agree that once a client has sent a `close notify` it shouldn't have to wait for a response and I *was* using an `async_shutdown` followed by an `async_write` as you've described here and in your (excellent) [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error/25703699#25703699)

Unfortunately, using the boost 1.59, the call to `async_write` now fails by crashing in `engine.ipp` instead of calling the callback with `SSL_R_PROTOCOL_IS_SHUTDOWN`!

So how best disconnect the SSL socket and not crash?

Comment: @kenba I will try to find some time to investigate it.  Is the application guaranteeing that all asynchronous operations are being performed within the same implicit or explicit strand?  Often times, crashes with Boost.Asio SSL are the result of violating concurrency requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Tanner it would be great if you could find the cause. The application in question is single threaded so there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: Please accept my sincerest apologies @TannerSansbury. I fully support you in your plans for a PR to change SSL shutdown to not wait for the peer's `close_notify`. However, please be aware that [Chris Kohlhoff](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff) hasn't been active on his GitHub account for over 3 months. I don't know whether he's busy preparing for including `asio` in [C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4370.html) or what? I just hope he's OK. For what its' worth, my respect for you is now greater than ever.

Comment: Calling both `async_shutdown` and `async_write` at once is problematic in some use-cases. For example when implementing a composed operation. There will be two pending completions, which can in theory complete in any order. There will be two error codes to deal with, etc...  Could the same result be achieved by simply calling `async_write` in the completion handler for `async_shutdown`? This way, there is only ever one pending completion.

Comment: @Vinnie The intention of initiating an `async_write()` with an outstanding `async_shutdown()` is to detect when the local write-side of the stream has shutdown, allowing one to free resources without having to wait for the remote peer to shutdown their side of the ssl stream.  If one waits for the `async_shutdown` to complete, then `async_write` would no longer be necessary.

Comment: I hit the problem mentioned by **kenba** where there was a crash in engine.ipp, it was only occurred when multiple threads were running `ioservice::run`. It also required 32 threads to hit it. As **Tanner Sansbury** indicated it was due to violating the SSL concurrency issue. The fix was to strand the shutdown and the write:
``ssl_socket.async_shutdown(strand_.wrap(..) );
const char buffer[] = "";
async_write(ssl_socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), strand_.wrap(....));`` - hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably late to answer this but I want to report my experience.
This solution so far (using boost 1.78) did not produce any visible error on the client nor the server:

```
// sock type is boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>

sock->shutdown(ec);       

sock->lowest_layer().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

sock->lowest_layer().cancel(ec);

sock->lowest_layer().close();
```

Sandbox server with: `openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key -4 -debug`

With this solution the server gets this after the `sock->shutdown(ec)`.

```
read from 0x55e5dff8c960 [0x55e5dff810f8] (19 bytes => 19 (0x13))
0000 - 44 bc 11 5b a9 b4 ee 51-48 e0 18 f7 99 a7 a8 a9   D..[...QH.......
0010 - 21 1a 60                                          !.`
DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

Before I was using this code (used for both plain TCP and ssl socket)

```
sock->lowest_layer().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

sock->lowest_layer().cancel(ec);

sock->lowest_layer().close();
```

The old code, when leveraging ssl socket, produced this error on the server:

```
read from 0x55eb3d40b430 [0x55eb3d423513] (5 bytes => 0 (0x0))
ERROR
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

As mentioned before, to avoid this behavior a `close_notify` should be sent out by the client using [ssl::stream::async_shutdown](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_shutdown.html) or [ssl::stream::shutdown](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/shutdown.html)

The trick of `async_write()` could be useful in case you want to leverage the `async_shutdown()` function instead of the synchronous `shutdown()`

Comment: Did you test this with a server that does not shutdown the connection properly?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my response in case it helps people working with newer versions of Boost.
In my case, I'm using Boost 1.82.0 and I've implemented the first of the options proposed by [@tanner-sansbury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32054476/16103640) where a combination of `ssl_stream.async_shutdown` and `ssl_stream.lowest_layer()->close()` are used.

The code for the client and server side look identical (only the logging messages and optionally variable name change):

```
tls_socket.lowest_layer().cancel();  // Cancels all ongoing operations
// Sends a 'close_notify' message to the server
tls_socket_ptr_.async_shutdown([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {           
        timer_->cancel();
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "CloseSocket - Cleanly shutdown SSL stream. Now we'll shutdown the socket..." << std::endl;
            ClosePlainTCPSocket();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "BrainClient::CloseSocket - Something went wrong while shutting down SSL stream! Exitting anyway..." << std::endl;
        }
    });


void ClosePlainTCPSocket()
{
    boost::system::error_code tcp_socket_shutdown_ec;
    tls_socket.lowest_layer().shutdown(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, tcp_socket_shutdown_ec);

    if (!tcp_socket_shutdown_ec)
    {
        std::cout << "BrainClient::ClosePlainTCPSocket - TCP socket was successfully shutdown, closing socket..." << std::endl;
        tls_socket_ptr_.lowest_layer().close();
    }
}
```

Additionally, I've added a `boost::asio::steady_timer` after the code above so I don't wait forever for the async_shutdown to finish. If the timer times out I report an error and try to close the server end synchronously with `shutdown()`.

Pardon me if there's any bug in the code since I've taken only part of my code to simplify the example as much as possible.