# Async read completes, but buffer does not contain expected results

Tags: c++, asynchronous, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I've been following numerous tutorials online on learning Asynchronous Networking in Asio, so if I've made a really obvious mistake, there's your explanation.

Nonetheless, I've written a program that sets up both a client and server simultaneously and tries to communicate between the two. Simply connecting and making requests to send/receive data seem to be working fine, but the data itself isn't being sent.

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#include<asio.hpp>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<mutex>
#include<memory>
#include<functional>

#define IPADDRESS   "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT        "6118"

enum side_type {
    t_server, t_client
};

std::mutex m_lock;
std::array<char, 32> clientBuffer;
std::array<char, 32> serverBuffer;
bool stop(false);

void read_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket>, std::array<char, 32> &, side_type &);
void write_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket>, std::array<char, 32> &, side_type &);

void read_function(const asio::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_read, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::array<char, 32> & buffer, side_type & type) {
    if (ec) return;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    char value = buffer[0];
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
        string type_str = type == t_server ? "Server" : "Client";
        cout << "Value of " << int(value) << " read by " << type_str << "." << endl;
    }
    if (value >= 100) stop = true;
    else {
        if(type == t_server)
            buffer[0] = value + 1;
        socket->async_write_some(asio::buffer(&buffer[0], buffer.max_size()), bind(write_function, _1, _2, socket, buffer, type));
    }
}

void write_function(const asio::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_written, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, std::array<char, 32> & buffer, side_type & type) {
    if (ec) return;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    socket->async_read_some(asio::buffer(&buffer[0], buffer.max_size()), bind(read_function, _1, _2, socket, buffer, type));
}

void work_function(std::shared_ptr<asio::io_service> io_service) {
    using namespace std;
    asio::error_code ec;
    while (!ec) {
        try {
            io_service->run(ec);
            break;
        }
        catch (exception & e) {
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
            cout << "Exception thrown: \"" << e.what() << "\"." << endl;
        }
    }
}

void connect_function(const asio::error_code & ec, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
    if (ec) {
        cout << "Error Connecting: " << ec << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Successful Connection!" << endl;
        socket->async_read_some(asio::buffer(&clientBuffer[0], clientBuffer.max_size()), bind(read_function, _1, _2, socket, clientBuffer, t_client));
    }
}

void accept_function(const asio::error_code & ec, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(m_lock);
    if (ec) {
        cout << "Error Accepting: " << ec << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Successful Acception!" << endl;
        serverBuffer[0] = 0;
        socket->async_write_some(asio::buffer(&serverBuffer[0], serverBuffer.max_size()), bind(write_function, _1, _2, socket, serverBuffer, t_server));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    shared_ptr<asio::io_service> io_service(new asio::io_service());
    shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work(new asio::io_service::work(*io_service));

    vector<shared_ptr<thread>> threads;
    int num_of_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    for (auto i = 0; i < thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
        threads.push_back(shared_ptr<thread>(new thread(work_function, io_service)));
    }

    using namespace asio::ip;
    tcp::resolver resolver(*io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(IPADDRESS, PORT);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator;

    cout << "Connecting to " << endpoint << endl;

    shared_ptr<tcp::acceptor> acceptor(new tcp::acceptor(*io_service));
    shared_ptr<tcp::socket> acc_socket(new tcp::socket(*io_service));
    shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket(new tcp::socket(*io_service));

    acceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
    acceptor->set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(false));
    acceptor->bind(endpoint);
    acceptor->listen(asio::socket_base::max_connections);
    acceptor->async_accept(*acc_socket, bind(accept_function, _1, acc_socket));

    asio::error_code ec;
    socket->async_connect(endpoint, bind(connect_function, _1, socket));

    //while (!stop);

    cout << "Press Any Key to Continue..." << endl;
    cin.get();

    socket->shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
    socket->close(ec);

    work.reset();

    while (!io_service->stopped());

    for (shared_ptr<thread> & t : threads) {
        t->join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As output, I've been getting the following:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:6118
Press Any Key to Continue...
Successful Connection!
Successful Acception!
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 0 read by Server.
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 1 read by Server.
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 2 read by Server.
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 3 read by Server.
......
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 98 read by Server.
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 99 read by Server.
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 100 read by Server.
```

However, what I'm expecting is:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:6118
Press Any Key to Continue...
Successful Connection!
Successful Acception!
Value of 0 read by Client.
Value of 0 read by Server.
Value of 1 read by Client.
Value of 1 read by Server.
Value of 2 read by Client.
Value of 2 read by Server.
Value of 3 read by Client.
Value of 3 read by Server.
......
Value of 98 read by Client.
Value of 98 read by Server.
Value of 99 read by Client.
Value of 99 read by Server.
Value of 100 read by Client.
Value of 100 read by Server.
```

Clearly what's happening is that the Server buffer is getting updated (when I manually increment the value), while the Client Buffer never gets updated by the async_read_some function. Additionally, because the client buffer never gets updated, the server is just reading in old values (also without getting updated) and thus *technically* has incorrect output as well. However, I don't know what's wrong. I'm passing in all my buffers the way I think I'm supposed to, and all the functions seem to be bound correctly, but the data isn't being passed. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: What version of boost are you using?

Comment: Or, if not using boost, what version of asio?

Comment: I'm using the non-Boost version of Asio. Version 1.10.6. Which is the most recent non-dev version of the code located here: http://think-async.com/Asio/Download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a copy of the buffer is being bound to the completion handler, which is a different buffer than that which is provided to the asynchronous operations:

```cpp
socket->async_read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), std::bind(..., buffer, ...));
                                  // ^~~~~~ = reference      ^~~~~~ = copy
```

In the above snippet, the `async_read_some()` operation will operate on `buffer`, and the completion handler will be provided a copy of `buffer` before the operation has made any modifications.  To resolve this, use `std::ref()` to pass a reference to `std::bind()`.

```cpp
socket->async_read_some(asio::buffer(buffer), std::bind(..., std::ref(buffer), ...));
                                  // ^~~~~~ = reference               ^~~~~~ = reference
```

In this case, passing a reference will also fix a potential case where undefined behavior could have been invoked.  The [`async_write_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html) and [`async_read_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) operations require that ownership of the underlying buffer memory is retained by the caller, who must guarantee that it remains valid until the completion handler is called.  When `std::bind()` was being provided a copy of the buffer, the buffer's lifetime was bound to the functor object returned from `std::bind()`, which may have ended before the completion handler was invoked.

```cpp
void read_function(
  ...,
  std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket,
  std::array<char, 32>& buffer,
  ...)
{
  ...
  socket->async_write_some(asio::buffer(buffer), handler);
} // buffer's lifetime ends shortly after returning from this function

socket->async_read_some(
  asio::buffer(buffer),
  std::bind(&read_function, ..., socket, buffer, ...));
```

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01f06c2fc680455b) the fundamental problem and behavior:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

int get_data(std::array<char, 32>& data)
{
  return data[0];
}

int main()
{
  std::array<char, 32> data;
  data[0] = 0;
  auto fn_copy = std::bind(&get_data, data);
  auto fn_ref = std::bind(&get_data, std::ref(data));
  data[0] = 1;
  assert(0 == fn_copy());
  assert(1 == fn_ref());
}
```

Comment: Fantastic writeup, this solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your `Readhandler` and `WriteHander`:

```
void read_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket>, std::array<char, 32> &, side_type &);
void write_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t, std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket>, std::array<char, 32> &, side_type &);
```

don't conform to the asio [Read handler](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) and [Write handler](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/WriteHandler.html) requirements. I.e. just:

```
void read_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t);
void write_function(const asio::error_code&, size_t);
```

Your application needs to "own" the read and write buffers and not expect their locations to be sent back to you by the handlers. If you use `clientBuffer` and `serverBuffer` where appropriate, it should work correctly.

Comment: The ReadHandler and WriteHandler provided to the operations do conform with the handler requirements, as the resulting functor from `std::bind()` meets the expression requirement of `h(ec, s`) where `ec` is an lvalue `const error_code` and `s` is an lvalue `const size_t`.  Asio performs some concept checking and failing to meet a type requirement will often result in a compilation error.

Comment: @TannerSansbury your comment is unnecessary and not strictly correct. Such a shame, I used to respect you...

Comment: I meant no ill-intentions or disrespect when posting my comment.  I was trying to accentuate that while `read_function` and `write_function` do not adhere to the respective handler type requirements, it is acceptable to use `std::bind()`  to meet those requirements, as was done in the original question.  Is trying to provide additional information on potential point of confusion to those who are still learning a library a bad choice?  Also, if the information provided was not strictly correct, then please improve it and provide the corrected information for the benefit of others.

Comment: @TannerSansbury I'm sure that you posted your comment with the best of intentions and I know that my answer was not perfect. However, I would respect you more, if you could spend your time and talent finding the answer to the [SSL disconnect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket) question I asked over a month ago instead commenting on this relatively simple bug. But, to that end, although accepatable, I'd recommend that @Xirema use `lambda`s in future since I find that `std::bind` leads to these kinds of bugs.

Comment: For what is it worth, I have over 60 hours logged against trying to identify the SSL disconnect bug, and I am still actively work on it.  For the few times I have been able to get it to crash locally, debugging points to different conditions.  In the end, I would like to submit a PR to Asio and Boost.Asio that changes shutdown errors a bit and provide first-class support for shutdown operations that does not wait for the peer's `close_notify`.  Sometimes I am short on time and not on a development machine, so will answer some of these questions.