# Segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) using boost asio 1.64 when trying to close a SSL socket

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I don't understand how I must close a `boost::asio` ssl socket. I have tried it in several ways but it always raises a `Segmentation fault` in some moment.

I have been reading the following post to solve this situation:
[boost asio ssl async_shutdown always finishes with an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error/25703699#25703699)

Specifically, I am trying to implement the

> PartyA initiates shutdown() and waits for PartyB to respond with a
>   shutdown()

Notice that both the client and the server are running in `localhost`.

Below is the client code:

```
typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SSLSocket;

MyClass::MyClass(const std::string &url,
    const std::string &port) throw() :
    m_socket(NULL), m_url(url), m_port(port), m_isConnected(false)
{
}

void MyClass::disconnect()
{
  // See the section "the disconnect method"
}

bool MyClass::tryConnect() throw()
{ 
  boost::asio::io_service ioService;
  boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
  m_socket = new SSLSocket(ioService, ctx);

  tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
  tcp::resolver::query query(m_url, m_port);

  tcp::resolver::iterator end;
  tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

  boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
  boost::asio::connect(m_socket->lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator, error);

  if(endpoint_iterator == end || error)
  {
    m_isConnected = false;
  }
  else
  {
    m_socket->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
    m_socket->handshake(SSLSocket::client);

    m_isConnected = true;
  }

  return m_isConnected;
}

void MyClass::write(const std::string &message)
{
  boost::asio::write(*m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
}

std::string MyClass::readUntil(const std::string &until)
{
  boost::asio::read_until(*m_socket, response, until);
  ...
  return response;
}

int main()
{
  MyClass mc(...);

  while(true)
  {
    bool connected = mc.isConnected();

    if(!connected)
    {
      connected = mc.tryConnect();
    }

    if(connected)
    {
      mc.send(...);
      std::string resp = mc.readUntil(...);
      mc.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

## The disconnect method

I have read the post linked in the comments and I have updated both the ssl server and the client. Now, both of them perform the `shutdown()` operation to close the ssl connection properly, but I still have an error when closing the socket.

I have updated the `disconnect()` method (which is always where the program crashes) as following:

```
...
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> *m_socket;
...
void MyClass::disconnect()
{
  // Shutdown the connection
  // TODO is this the correct way to close a boost asio socket?
  if(m_socket != NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "shutting down the socket, thread = " <<
        pthread_self() << std::endl;

    // I have checked that the thread is always the same, so the problem 
    // is not related with race conditions or similar.

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    m_socket->lowest_layer().shutdown(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);

    std::cout <<
        "Shut down, err = " << ec << ", " <<
        "Category: " << ec.category().name() << std::endl;

    if(!ec)
    {
      std::cout << "closing the socket, thread = " <<
         pthread_self() << std::endl;

      if(m_socket->lowest_layer().is_open())
      {
        m_socket->lowest_layer().close(ec);
      }

      std::cout <<
        "Socket closed, err = " << ec << ", " <<  "Category: " <<
        ec.category().name() << std::endl;

      if(!ec)
      {
        std::cout << "Deleting socket... " << std::endl;
        delete m_socket;
        m_socket = NULL;
        std::cout << "Socket deleted" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }

  m_isConnected = false;
}
```

## The error backtrace

The bkactrace (from the disconnect method) is here:

```
#0  0x4158114f in boost::system::error_code::operator=<boost::asio::error::basic_errors> (this=0x1d, val=boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    at .../include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:344
#1  0x41587308 in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::deregister_descriptor (this=0x46463045, descriptor=27, descriptor_data=@0x812ef14: 0x8151ea8, 
    closing=true) at .../include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp:351
#2  0x41588550 in boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::close (this=0x812efbc, impl=..., ec=...)
    at .../include/boost/asio/detail/impl/reactive_socket_service_base.ipp:104
#3  0x415885da in boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::close (this=0x812efa8, impl=..., ec=...)
    at .../include/boost/asio/stream_socket_service.hpp:174
#4  0x41588630 in boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::close (this=0x812ef08, ec=...)
    at .../include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:385
#5  0x41576383 in MyClass::disconnect (this=0x80a6f58) at ...
```

Inspecting the `frame 1`, it can be seen that the error that boost is creating is `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted;`

In addition, running the process with gdb, simetimes I see the following **assertion failure**:

```
pthread_mutex_lock.c:312: __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion `(-(e)) != 3 || !robust' failed.
```

Comment: SIGABRT often indicates an assertion failure. Have you inspected the stack trace from the crash? How exactly do you kill this process? In your code snippet there are no threads and no signal handling.  Also you call `resolver.resolve(query)` twice for no reason.

Comment: The answer to this question may help you: [What is the proper way to securely disconnect an asio SSL socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I was openning the socket in a method like:

```
void connect()
{
  ...
  boost::asio::io_service m_ioService
  ...
  m_sock = new SSLSocket(m_ioService, ...)
}
```

When the `connect` method returns, `m_ioService` is out of scope, so the socket crashes since the `ioService` has been deleted. Notice that the `m_ioService` is passed by reference, moreover, it is non-copyable.