# TLSv1.3 post-handshake: server only verifies the client certificate when the connection is closed

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio, handshake, tls1.3

### Info / TL;DR:

The problem still exists but a workaround is located at the end of this post

### The problem:

I have a problem where I just don't know what to do. I am using Boost 1.83 and OpenSSL 3.1 and I am trying to create a TLS server with post-handshake support. In other words, for certain client requests, I want to trigger client authentication after the TLS handshake. The TLS message exchange seems to work, but the order of processing is not correct. Currently, the server sends the response and then verifies the client's authenticity, because OpenSSL does not trigger the callback until the TLS connection is closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Sometimes the server still sends data after a "close notify" message, which is also strange. Can anyone help?

See below for minimal example of the server and a matching client.
The problem also occurs with an asynchronous boost/asio implementation.

Here is the output after communicating with the client:

```
server ready
acceptor ok
handshake ok
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
2nd handshake ok
write ok; server response message (27 bytes transmitted): this is the server response
shutdown the connection...
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=RootCA_ST/L=RootCA_L/O=RootCA_O/OU=RootCA_OU/CN=RootCA_CN
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=TLS_Client_ST/L=TLS_Client_L/O=TLS_Client_O/OU=TLS_Client_OU/CN=TLS_Client_CN
shutdown: The operation was completed successfully

END
```

Here is the output with additional debug information:

```
server ready
acceptor ok
TLS status: before SSL initialization
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
2nd handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
write ok; server response message (27 bytes transmitted): this is the server response
shutdown the connection...
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=RootCA_ST/L=RootCA_L/O=RootCA_O/OU=RootCA_OU/CN=RootCA_CN
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=TLS_Client_ST/L=TLS_Client_L/O=TLS_Client_O/OU=TLS_Client_OU/CN=TLS_Client_CN
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
shutdown: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

END
```

Here is the Wireshark output with the markers when certain code sections of the server are reached (127.0.0.1: client; 127.0.0.5: server):

```
No.     Time            Source     Destination   Protocol  Length   Info
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 0.000662       127.0.0.1   127.0.0.5     TLSv1.3   287      Client Hello

<TCP: acceptor>
<TLS: handshake>

      2 16.029938      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   1478     Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Application Data, Application Data, Application Data, Application Data
      3 16.032142      127.0.0.1   127.0.0.5     TLSv1.3   124      Change Cipher Spec, Application Data
      4 16.032351      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   554      Application Data, Application Data
      5 16.032378      127.0.0.1   127.0.0.5     TLSv1.3   79       Application Data   --> this is the client request message

<TLS: read>
<TLS: post-handshake authentication of the client --> SSL_verify_client_post_handshake()>
<TLS: post-handshake authentication of the client --> 2nd handshake>

      6 51.594902      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   143      Application Data
      7 51.598791      127.0.0.1   127.0.0.5     TLSv1.3   1323     Application Data, Application Data, Application Data

<TLS: write>

      8 62.972860      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   93       Application Data   --> this is the server response message ()

<TLS: shutdown>

      9 68.777818      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   68       Application Data   --> close_notify of the server
     10 68.779306      127.0.0.1   127.0.0.5     TLSv1.3   68       Application Data   --> close_notify of the client
     11 68.780150      127.0.0.5   127.0.0.1     TLSv1.3   1674     Application Data, Application Data   --> well... I dont know how this happens here.

< --- verifyCertificate is invoked --- >
<end of function>
```

this is strange....  after the 'post-handshake authentication' in the code the server sends a certificate request and gets this also from the client, but the callback for the verification is called only after the shutdown(). ...there it is of course too late and it should happen before <TLS: write>.

any ideas? Do I still have to "instruct"/configure OpenSSL somehow?

**Replying to sehe**

Hello sehe. Thank you for your support and the time you spend for me. I also thought of using Cancellation, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my use case. I don't understand the behavior of my code anymore and that frustrates me.
Maybe I'm blind and can't see the real problem. Unfortunately, I can't find any third-party code or examples to see how others have solved it.

The behavior of the server is strange....
If socket.write() is called after the second handshake (in the server code: 'TLS: post-handshake authentication'), then the client certificate is verified after shutdown() (see server trace above).

If a socket.read() is called after the second handshake, then the client certificate is verified immediately, but read() (or read_some()) blocks because the client sends nothing more:

```
server ready
acceptor ok
TLS status: before SSL initialization
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
2nd handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=RootCA_ST/L=RootCA_L/O=RootCA_O/OU=RootCA_OU/CN=RootCA_CN
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=TLS_Client_ST/L=TLS_Client_L/O=TLS_Client_O/OU=TLS_Client_OU/CN=TLS_Client_CN
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
```

If a socket.read() is called after the second handshake, and the client sends a second message after that, read() will no longer block, but the certificate will not be verified at all:

```
server ready
acceptor ok
TLS status: before SSL initialization
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
2nd handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
write ok; server response message (27 bytes transmitted): this is the server response
shutdown the connection...
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
shutdown: application data after close notify (SSL routines)

END
```

.... and with socket.async_read_some() the server will not block either, but the client certificate will also not be verified:

```
server ready
acceptor ok
TLS status: before SSL initialization
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write finished
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: TLSv1.3 early data
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS read finished
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
read ok; client request message (30 bytes received): hello server, authenticate me!
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
TLS status: SSLv3/TLS write certificate request
2nd handshake ok
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
write ok; server response message (27 bytes transmitted): this is the server response
shutdown the connection...
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
TLS status: SSL negotiation finished successfully
shutdown: decryption failed or bad record mac (SSL routines)
```

Here the full example code and the test certificates plus keys

TLSv1.3 server

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class TlsServer
{
public:
    TlsServer(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, uint16_t port)
        :
        m_ioService(ioService),
        m_acceptor(ioService, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
        m_context(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv13_server)
    {
        // set certificates
        m_context.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
        m_context.use_certificate_chain_file("server_cert.pem");
        m_context.use_private_key_file("server_key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

        // certificate callback
        SSL_CTX_set_verify(m_context.native_handle(), SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | SSL_VERIFY_POST_HANDSHAKE, nullptr);
        m_context.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&TlsServer::verifyCertificate, this, _1, _2));

        std::cout << "server ready" << std::endl;
        wholeProcedure();
    }

    void wholeProcedure()
    {
        boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket(m_ioService, m_context);
        boost::system::error_code ec;

        // additional informations (optinal)
        SSL_set_msg_callback(socket.native_handle(),
            [](int write_p, int version, int content_type, const void* buf, size_t len, SSL* ssl, void* arg)
            {std::cout << "TLS status: \t" << SSL_state_string_long(ssl) << std::endl; });

        // TCP: acceptor
        m_acceptor.accept(socket.lowest_layer(), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "acceptor error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "acceptor ok" << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: handshake
        socket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server, ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "handshake error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "handshake ok" << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: read (receive client request)
        std::vector<char> buffer(2048);
        std::size_t bytesReceived = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer.size()), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "read error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string requestStr(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + bytesReceived);
            std::cout << "read ok; client request message (" << bytesReceived << " bytes received): " << requestStr << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: post-handshake authentication of the client
        if (SSL_verify_client_post_handshake(socket.native_handle()) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "post-handshake error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        socket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server, ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "2nd handshake error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "2nd handshake ok" << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: 2nd read (receive client request)
        bytesReceived = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer.size()), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "read error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string requestStr(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + bytesReceived);
            std::cout << "read ok; client request message (" << bytesReceived << " bytes received): " << requestStr << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: write (send server response)
        std::string responseStr = "this is the server response";
        std::vector<unsigned char> responseMsg(responseStr.begin(), responseStr.end());
        std::size_t bytesTransmitted = boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(responseMsg, responseMsg.size()), ec);
        if (ec)
        {
            std::cout << "write error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "write ok; server response message (" << bytesTransmitted << " bytes transmitted): " << responseStr << std::endl;
        }

        // TLS: shutdown
        std::cout << "shutdown the connection..." << std::endl;
        socket.shutdown(ec);
        std::cout << "shutdown: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }

    bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
    {
        // get subject name of the certificate
        char subject_name[256];
        X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

        if (preverified == false)
        {
            std::cout << "client certificate invalid: " << subject_name << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "client certificate valid: " << subject_name << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& m_ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    boost::asio::ssl::context m_context;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        uint16_t port = 2405;
        boost::asio::io_service ioService;
        TlsServer tlsServer(ioService, port);
        ioService.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

TLSv1.3 client

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class TlsClient
{
public:
    TlsClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoint)
        :
        m_buffer(2048),
        m_socket(io_service, context)
    {
        m_socket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
        m_socket.set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&TlsClient::verifyCertificate, this, _1, _2));

        SSL_set_post_handshake_auth(m_socket.native_handle(), true); // enable post-handshake authentication
        TlsClient::connect(endpoint);
    }

    void connect(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoint)
    {
        boost::asio::async_connect(m_socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint,
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
            {
            if (error)
            {
            std::cout << "connect() failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
            }
            handshake();
            }
        );
    }

    void handshake()
    {
        m_socket.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
            if (error)
            {
            std::cout << "handshake() failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
            }
            sendRequest();
            }
        );
    }

    void sendRequest()
    {
        char request[] = "hello server, authenticate me!";
        boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(request, std::strlen(request)),
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytesTransmitted)
            {
            if (error)
            {
            std::cout << "sendRequest() failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            return;
            }
            std::cout << "sendRequest() successful (" << bytesTransmitted << " bytes transmitted)" << std::endl;
            receiveResponse();
            }
        );
    }

    void receiveResponse()
    {
        m_socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(m_buffer, m_buffer.size()),
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytesReceived)
            {
            if (!error)
            {
            std::cout << "receiveResponse() successful (" << bytesReceived << " bytes received)" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "server response message: ";
            std::cout.write(m_buffer.data(), bytesReceived);
            std::cout << std::endl;
            receiveResponse();
            }
            else if ((error) && (error == boost::asio::error::eof)) // 'end of file' is fine
            {
            std::cout << "receiveResponse(): close_notify received" << std::endl;
            shutdown();
            }
            else
            {
            std::cout << "receiveResponse() failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            shutdown();
            }
            }
        );
    }

    void shutdown()
    {
        m_socket.async_shutdown(
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error)
            {
            if (error)
            {
            std::cout << "shutdown() failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
            }
        );
    }

    bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
    {
        // get subject name of the certificate
        char subject_name[256];
        X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
        if (preverified == false)
        {
            std::cout << "certificate invalid: " << subject_name << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "certificate valid: " << subject_name << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_socket;
    std::vector<char> m_buffer;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        auto endpoint = resolver.resolve("127.0.0.5", "2405");

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv13_client);
        ctx.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
        ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("client_cert.pem");
        ctx.use_private_key_file("client_key.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

        TlsClient client(io_context, ctx, endpoint);
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Certificates and key (Base64/PEM format)

```
client_cert.pem
================================================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

client_key.pem
================================================================
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEINcbzvL7XAAT2iZVFzjsOqWd7TvDW9jMF/w6E/2+cXkboAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEBP2SsBhtXWgV1ph/W0vGN3BDhwZJIyVbPgQL/vZRXwffQ6HP1HUt
REXCEuwdCCqWQrNTwd12CM9o3F2mf9Bkqg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

server_cert.pem
================================================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

server_key.pem
================================================================
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIMfzK4phpnO22uVPYxCg7EjnNFub9OH/ds61chjxX0CAoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAEKjbEQWATZKj2Fdk2RzUMeYyxftoFMGnk2Fahn8SSC6sEKSDt4ZnB
J3D7b5vcCIC/E51d9q+dzPneA4eBpy/abg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

rootCA_cert.pem
================================================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

## Workaround

### What do I want:

Here is a very brief description of what is important to me:

I have a TLSv1.3 server and some TLSv1.3 clients, some of which need to be authenticated and some of which do not. The need is decided after the client request is processed. This is the case, for example, when certain resources or data are requested by the client.

The basic idea was to solve this with post-handshake authentication (PHA). However, it is currently causing problems.

### Workaround:

With OpenSSL/Boost, it is possible to have the server request the client certificate at the beginning of the TLS handshake. The server can be configured to continue the handshake even if the client does not send a certificate:

```cpp
context.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer); // boost variant
SSL_CTX_set_verify(context, SSL_VERIFY_PEER); // OpenSSL variant
```

If the client does this, it is authenticated instantly.

If I process the client request message after the handshake and authentication is required, then I can check if this has been done:

```cpp
    if (SSL_get_peer_certificate(m_socket.native_handle()) != NULL)
    {
        if (SSL_get_verify_result(m_socket.native_handle()) == X509_V_OK) // warning: also returns 'X509_V_OK' if no cert present 
        {
            // ok: certificate received and valid
        }
        else
        {
            // fail: certificate received, but invalid
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // fail: no certificate received
    }
```

For my purposes this solution is good enough and maybe it will help others too.

kind regards,
*SBond*

PS: ...thank you **sehe** for your help and time :)

Comment: I haven't worked with post-handshake peer verification. Do you have a link to existing working openssl code (not necessarily C++ or Asio) that shows how it should work? Perhaps including some key/cert material might help in repro.

Comment: I solved the problem after 2 days of searching. It's so simple and stupid at the same time. ...I saw in Wireshark that the TLS messages (client certificate) are sent to the server, but of course I have to do a read() operation on the server to process them.  ...since I only sent data on the server side, I didn't check if there was still incoming data from the client. Since OpenSSL internally performs a read() on shutdown, these messages were processed after the TLS connection was closed. This also explains the odd packet order.

Comment: Please post this as an answer so people can find it. It also might have saved me (and possibility others too) considerable time,

Comment: Yes. ...unfortunately I am still struggling with the problem. When I call the boost function "socket.read_some()", it processes the TLS handshake messages I have already received and initiates client certificate verification. However, this function blocks until the client sends more data.  But that doesn't happen anymore because the client is just waiting for a response from the server. I'm currently looking in vain for an OpenSSL API that I can use to trigger the processing of the already received TLS handshake messages without blocking the rest of the TLS process. I don't have a solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After toying with this for a long time I reached the conclusion that the only way to ensure the verification preceeds the authentication response is to write another message in your protocol.

- I opted for a simple "VERIFICATION REQUEST"/"VERIFICATION RESPONSE" roundtrip,
- simply `async_wait(read|write)` on the lowest level socket wasn't enough
- neither was issueing an empty write (`send("")`)

I used an event to be able to asynchronously await the verification response. This may be overcomplicated when you do not want to allow any other messages to be sent before completing the verification step. In that case, simply close the connection when receiving an invalid verification response.

- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <deque>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using Socket = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;

   static bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
       // get subject name of the certificate
       char  subject_name[256];
       X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
       X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

       std::cout << "client certificate " << (preverified ? "valid" : "invalid") << ": " << subject_name
                 << std::endl;
       return preverified;
   }

   static void tlsDebug(int, int, int, void const*, size_t, SSL* ssl, void*) {
       static_cast<void>(ssl);
       // std::cout << "TLS status: " << SSL_state_string_long(ssl) << std::endl;
   }

   struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
       Session(Socket socket) : socket(std::move(socket)) {}

       void Run() {
           // TLS: handshake
           auto self = shared_from_this();
           socket.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server, [this, self](error_code ec) {
               std::cout << "handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
               reader();
           });
       }

     private:
       using time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point;
       Socket                  socket;
       asio::steady_timer      verification_response{socket.get_executor(), time_point::max()};
       size_t                  request_counter = 0;
       std::deque<std::string> outbox;
       std::string             req;

       void writer() {
           if (outbox.empty()) {
               std::cout << "writer idle (queue: " << outbox.size() << ")" << std::endl;
               return;
           }

           auto self = shared_from_this();
           // TLS: write
           asio::async_write(                //
               socket,                       //
               asio::buffer(outbox.front()), //
               [this, self](error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) {
                   std::cout << "wrote: '" << outbox.front() << "' (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                   if (!ec) {
                       outbox.pop_front();
                       writer();
                   }
               });
       }

       void shutdown() {
           // TLS: shutdown
           std::cout << "shutdown the connection..." << std::endl;
           auto self = shared_from_this();
           socket.async_shutdown(
               [self](error_code ec) { std::cout << "shutdown: " << ec.message() << std::endl; });
       }

       void send(std::string msg) {
           outbox.push_back(std::move(msg));
           if (outbox.size() == 1) {
               std::cout << "writer start (queue: " << outbox.size() << ")" << std::endl;
               writer();
           }
       }

       bool is_verified() const { return verification_response.expiry() <= std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); }

       void reader() {
           request_counter += 1;
           // TLS: read (receive client request)
           req.resize(2048);
           auto self = shared_from_this();
           socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(req), [this, self](error_code ec, size_t n) {
               std::cout << "read #" << request_counter << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;

               if (ec) {
                   std::cout << "reader completed" << std::endl;
                   return shutdown();
               }

               req.resize(n);
               std::cout << "client request #" << request_counter << ": '" << req << "'" << std::endl;

               if (req == "authentication request") {
                   if (is_verified()) {
                       send("ALREADY AUTHENTICATED");
                       return reader();
                   }

                   std::cout << "--- initiating post-handshake peer auth" << std::endl;
                   bool ok = SSL_verify_client_post_handshake(socket.native_handle());
                   std::cout << "post-handshake: " << (ok ? "OK" : "Failed") << std::endl;

                   send("VERIFICATION REQUEST");
                   reader(); // await VERIFICATION RESPONSE

                   verification_response.async_wait([this, self](error_code ec) {
                       if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                           socket.async_handshake( //
                               ssl::stream_base::server, [this, self](error_code ec) {
                                   std::cout << "2nd handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                   if (!ec) {
                                       verification_response.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::now());
                                       send("AUTHENTICATED");
                                       reader();
                                   }
                               });
                       } else {
                           std::cerr << "Verification failed" << std::endl;
                           shutdown();
                       }
                   });
               } else if (req == "VERIFICATION RESPONSE") {
                   verification_response.cancel_one(); // can only signal pending auth
               } else {
                   if (is_verified())
                       send("Authenticated response to '" + req + "'");
                   else
                       send("Generic response to '" + req + "'");
                   reader();
               }
           });
       }
   };

   struct TlsServer {
       TlsServer(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : acc(ex, {{}, port}) {}

       void Start() {
           // set certificates
           ctx.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("server_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_private_key_file("server_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);

           // certificate callback
           SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx.native_handle(),
                              SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | SSL_VERIFY_POST_HANDSHAKE,
                              nullptr);
           ctx.set_verify_callback(verifyCertificate);

           std::cout << "server ready" << std::endl;
           accept_loop();
       }

     private:
       tcp::acceptor            acc;
       ssl::context             ctx{ssl::context::tlsv13_server};
       ssl::stream<tcp::socket> s{acc.get_executor(), ctx};

       void accept_loop() {
           s = {acc.get_executor(), ctx};
           SSL_set_msg_callback(s.native_handle(), tlsDebug);

           acc.async_accept(s.lowest_layer(), [this](error_code ec) {
               std::cout << "acceptor: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

               if (!ec) {
                   std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(s))->Run();
                   accept_loop();
               }
           });
       }
   };

   int main() {
       try {
           asio::io_context ioc;
           TlsServer        s(ioc.get_executor(), 2405);
           s.Start();
           ioc.run();
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
       }

       std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
   }
  ```
- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <deque>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;

   class TlsClient {
     public:
       TlsClient(asio::any_io_executor ex, ssl::context& context, tcp::resolver::results_type endpoint)
           : m_socket(ex, context) {
           m_socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
           m_socket.set_verify_callback(verifyCertificate);

           SSL_set_post_handshake_auth(m_socket.native_handle(), true); // enable post-handshake authentication
           connect(endpoint);
       }

       void connect(tcp::resolver::results_type endpoint) {
           asio::async_connect( //
               m_socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint, [this](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "connect() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   handshake();
               });
       }

       void handshake() {
           m_socket.async_handshake( //
               ssl::stream_base::client, [this](error_code ec) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "handshake() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   sendRequest();
               });
       }

       void send(std::string msg, bool immediate = false) {
           if (immediate) {
               m_queue.push_front(std::move(msg));
               if (m_queue.size() == 1)
                   sendRequest();
           } else {
               m_queue.push_back(std::move(msg));
               if (m_queue.size() == 1)
               delayRequest();
           }
       }

       void sendRequest() {
           if (m_queue.empty()) {
               std::cout << "sendRequest() completed" << std::endl;
               return shutdown();
           }

           asio::async_write( //
               m_socket, asio::buffer(m_queue.front()), [this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "sendRequest() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   std::cout << "sendRequest() successful (" << n << " bytes transmitted)" << std::endl;
                   m_queue.pop_front();
                   receiveResponse();
               });
           std::cout << "sendRequest() initiated for '" << m_queue.front() << "'" << std::endl;
       }

       void receiveResponse() {
           m_buffer.resize(2048);
           m_socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(m_buffer), [this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
               std::cout << "receiveResponse() " << ec.message() << " (" << n << " bytes received)" << std::endl;
               if (!ec) {
                   m_buffer.resize(n);
                   std::cout << "server message: '" << m_buffer << "'" << std::endl;
                   if (m_buffer == "VERIFICATION REQUEST") {
                       std::cout << "allowing 2nd hanshake" << std::endl;
                       send("VERIFICATION RESPONSE", true);
                   }
                   return delayRequest();
               } else if (ec == asio::error::eof) { // 'end of file' is fine
                   std::cout << "receiveResponse(): close_notify received" << std::endl;
                   shutdown();
               }
           });
       }

       void delayRequest() {
           m_timer.expires_from_now((rand() % 3 + 1) * std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
           m_timer.async_wait([this](error_code) { sendRequest(); });
       }

       void shutdown() {
           m_socket.async_shutdown([/*this*/](error_code ec) {
               if (ec) {
                   std::cout << "shutdown() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
               }
           });
       }

       static bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
           char  subject_name[256];
           X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
           X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

           std::cout << "certificate " << (preverified ? "valid" : "invalid") << ": " << subject_name
                     << std::endl;
           return preverified;
       }

     private:
       std::deque<std::string> m_queue{
           "non-auth request", "ping heartbeat",         "authentication request",
           "first query",      "authentication request", "second query",
       };
       ssl::stream<tcp::socket> m_socket;
       asio::steady_timer       m_timer{m_socket.get_executor()};
       std::string              m_buffer;
   };

   int main() {
       try {
           asio::io_context ioc;
           auto             endpoint = tcp::resolver(ioc).resolve("127.0.0.5", "2405");

           ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv13_client);
           ctx.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("client_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_private_key_file("client_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);

           TlsClient client(ioc.get_executor(), ctx, endpoint);
           ioc.run();
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
       }

       std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
   }
  ```

Demo, first with correct client certificate, then disabling the rootCA so it fails:

[image]

In plain text:

```
server ready
acceptor: Success
handshake: Success
read #1: Success
client request #1: 'non-auth request'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Generic response to 'non-auth request'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #2: Success
client request #2: 'ping heartbeat'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Generic response to 'ping heartbeat'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #3: Success
client request #3: 'authentication request'
--- initiating post-handshake peer auth
post-handshake: OK
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'VERIFICATION REQUEST' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=RootCA_ST/L=RootCA_L/O=RootCA_O/OU=RootCA_OU/CN=RootCA_CN
client certificate valid: /C=DE/ST=TLS_Client_ST/L=TLS_Client_L/O=TLS_Client_O/OU=TLS_Client_OU/CN=TLS_Client_CN
read #4: Success
client request #4: 'VERIFICATION RESPONSE'
2nd handshake: Success
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'AUTHENTICATED' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #5: Success
client request #5: 'first query'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Authenticated response to 'first query'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #6: Success
client request #6: 'authentication request'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'ALREADY AUTHENTICATED' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #7: Success
client request #7: 'second query'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Authenticated response to 'second query'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #8: End of file
reader completed
shutdown the connection...
shutdown: Success
```

vs.

```
server ready
acceptor: Success
handshake: Success
read #1: Success
client request #1: 'non-auth request'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Generic response to 'non-auth request'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #2: Success
client request #2: 'ping heartbeat'
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'Generic response to 'ping heartbeat'' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
read #3: Success
client request #3: 'authentication request'
--- initiating post-handshake peer auth
post-handshake: OK
writer start (queue: 1)
wrote: 'VERIFICATION REQUEST' (Success)
writer idle (queue: 0)
client certificate invalid: /C=DE/ST=RootCA_ST/L=RootCA_L/O=RootCA_O/OU=RootCA_OU/CN=RootCA_CN
read #4: certificate verify failed (SSL routines)
reader completed
shutdown the connection...
shutdown: shutdown while in init (SSL routines)
```

Comment: I deleted [the other async solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332104/85371) as I could see that it didn't solve the ordering issue. I have become convinced openssl doesn't allow you to ensure the ordering unless you add application protocol, which I demonstrate here.

Comment: It's interesting how some seemingly small problems can get so out of hand :). You helped me a lot. Thank you so much.  :)

Comment: It's exactly why I spend the time. Just so I know how it works and don't run into a glitch like that later :)

Answer (score 1):

> ### **NOTE**
>
> [New answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327517/85371) in response to information added in the question.

Replying to

> of course I have to do a read() operation on the server to process them [...]
> Since OpenSSL internally performs a read() on shutdown, these messages were processed after the TLS connection was closed

> When I call the boost function "socket.read_some()", it processes the TLS handshake messages I have already received and initiates client certificate verification. However, this function blocks until the client sends more data

I think the reasonable standard option is to use asynchronous IO operations.

In that case it's "free" to always have a read pending, which will cause any TLS events to be processed implicitly.

Then when at some point you wish to close the SSL stream, you can issue `s.shutdown()` on it and it will return EOF from the pending read.

Be sure to run all operations on a strand to avoid data race on the ssl stream.

### Cancellation

Interestingly, [What is the proper way to securely disconnect an asio SSL socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket/32054476#32054476) suggests that the read can be `cancel()`-ed. However `ssl::stream<>` doesn't have that operation.

More interestingly, still, since 1.77.0 the async operations on `ssl::stream<>` *have added* documentation of their cancellation support. Reading those, you should be able to use bound cancellation slots, or cancel via the underlying socket.

### Code

I didn't really get the client certificates configured to actually test with your code¹

But I wanted to quickly check that `shutdown` will indeed cause an extant async `read` operation to complete, so here is that little tester:

```
//#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std::literals;

asio::awaitable<void> demo_ssl_client(uint16_t port) {
    std::cout << "coro start" << std::endl;

    constexpr auto token = asio::deferred;
    try {
        using S              = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
        using C              = ssl::context;

        C ctx(C::tlsv13_client);
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

        auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
        S    s(ex, ctx);
        co_await s.lowest_layer().async_connect({{}, port}, token);
        std::cout << "connected " << s.lowest_layer().remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        co_await s.async_handshake(S::client, token);
        co_await async_write(s, asio::buffer("hello world\n"sv), token);

        char dummy[1]{};
        s.async_read_some(asio::buffer(dummy, 1), [](auto ec, size_t xfer) {
            std::cout << "async_read_some: " << ec.message() << ", " << xfer << std::endl;
        });

        std::cout << "happily idling" << std::endl;
        co_await asio::steady_timer{ex, 3s}.async_wait(token);

        std::cout << "time for shutdown" << std::endl;
        co_await async_write(s, asio::buffer("bye world\n"sv), token);

        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            s.lowest_layer().cancel(ec); // cancel async_read_some
        }

        auto [ec] = co_await s.async_shutdown(as_tuple(token));
        std::cout << "shutdown completed (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        std::cout << "error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
    }

    co_await post(token);
    std::cout << "coro exit" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    co_spawn(ioc, demo_ssl_client(7878), asio::detached);

    ioc.run();
}
```

[image]

---

¹ (`openssl s_client` kept giving me CA errors, I know, I should up my PKI peer auth-fu one of these days)

Answer (score 1):

To the edited question, I was able to test with the added information, kudos for making the question so complete.

I was also able to circumvent the symptoms by simply rearrange the second read till after the response write, which allows the verification to take place regardless.

Note that it also appears like the 2nd handshake is optional: the client ert is also verified without it:

[image]

I arrive at the following simplified set of sources, where I modified the client to also send multiple requests:

- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using namespace std::placeholders;
   using namespace std::literals;

   class TlsServer {
     public:
       TlsServer(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port)
           : m_acceptor(ex, tcp::endpoint({}, port))
           , m_context(ssl::context::tlsv13_server) //
       {
           // set certificates
           m_context.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
           m_context.use_certificate_chain_file("server_cert.pem");
           m_context.use_private_key_file("server_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);

           // certificate callback
           SSL_CTX_set_verify(m_context.native_handle(),
                              SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT | SSL_VERIFY_POST_HANDSHAKE,
                              nullptr);
           m_context.set_verify_callback(bind(&TlsServer::verifyCertificate, this, _1, _2));

           std::cout << "server ready" << std::endl;
           wholeProcedure();
       }

       void wholeProcedure() {
           ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket(m_acceptor.get_executor(), m_context);
           error_code               ec;

           // additional informations (optinal)
           SSL_set_msg_callback(socket.native_handle(),
                                [](int /*write_p*/, int /*version*/, int /*content_type*/, void const* /*buf*/,
                                   size_t /*len*/, SSL* ssl, void* /*arg*/) {
                                    std::cout << "TLS status: " << SSL_state_string_long(ssl) << std::endl;
                                });

           // TCP: acceptor
           m_acceptor.accept(socket.lowest_layer(), ec);
           std::cout << "acceptor: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

           // TLS: handshake
           socket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::server, ec);
           std::cout << "handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

           // TLS: read (receive client request)

           auto receive = [&socket, i = 0]() mutable {
               i += 1;
               error_code  ec;
               std::string req(2048, '\0');
               size_t      n = socket.read_some(asio::buffer(req), ec);
               std::cout << "read #" << i << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
               if (!ec) {
                   req.resize(n);
                   std::cout << "read ok; client request #" << i << ": " << quoted(req) << std::endl;
               }
           };

           receive();

           // TLS: post-handshake authentication of the client
           std::cout << "--- initiating post-handshake peer auth" << std::endl;
           bool ok = SSL_verify_client_post_handshake(socket.native_handle());
           std::cout << "post-handshake: " << (ok ? "OK" : "Failed") << std::endl;

           //socket.handshake(ssl::stream_base::server, ec);
           //std::cout << "2nd handshake: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

           // TLS: write (send server response)
           /*size_t n =*/asio::write(socket, asio::buffer("this is the server response"sv), ec);
           std::cout << "write: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

           // TLS: 2nd read (receive client request)
           receive();

           // TLS: shutdown
           std::cout << "shutdown the connection..." << std::endl;
           socket.shutdown(ec);
           std::cout << "shutdown: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
       }

       bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
           // get subject name of the certificate
           char  subject_name[256];
           X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
           X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

           std::cout << "client certificate " << (preverified ? "valid" : "invalid") << ": " << subject_name
                     << std::endl;
           return preverified;
       }

     private:
       tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
       ssl::context  m_context;
   };

   int main() {
       try {
           asio::io_context ioc;
           TlsServer        tlsServer(ioc.get_executor(), 2405);
           ioc.run();
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
       }

       std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
   }
  ```
- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
   #include <deque>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   namespace ssl  = asio::ssl;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using namespace std::placeholders;

   class TlsClient {
     public:
       TlsClient(asio::any_io_executor ex, ssl::context& context, tcp::resolver::results_type endpoint)
           : m_socket(ex, context) {
           m_socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
           m_socket.set_verify_callback(bind(&TlsClient::verifyCertificate, this, _1, _2));

           SSL_set_post_handshake_auth(m_socket.native_handle(), true); // enable post-handshake authentication
           connect(endpoint);
       }

       void connect(tcp::resolver::results_type endpoint) {
           asio::async_connect( //
               m_socket.lowest_layer(), endpoint, [this](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "connect() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   handshake();
               });
       }

       void handshake() {
           m_socket.async_handshake( //
               ssl::stream_base::client, [this](error_code ec) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "handshake() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   sendRequest();
               });
       }

       void sendRequest() {
           if (m_requests.empty()) {
               return shutdown();
           }

           asio::async_write( //
               m_socket, asio::buffer(m_requests.front()), [this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                   if (ec) {
                       std::cout << "sendRequest() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                       return;
                   }
                   std::cout << "sendRequest() successful (" << n << " bytes transmitted)" << std::endl;
                   m_requests.pop_front();
                   receiveResponse();
               });
           std::cout << "sendRequest() initiated for " << std::quoted(m_requests.front()) << std::endl;
       }

       void receiveResponse() {
           m_buffer.resize(2048);
           m_socket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(m_buffer), [this](error_code ec, size_t n) {
               std::cout << "receiveResponse() " << ec.message() << " (" << n << " bytes received)" << std::endl;
               if (!ec) {
                   m_buffer.resize(n);
                   std::cout << "server response message: " << std::quoted(m_buffer) << std::endl;
                   return sendRequest();
               } else if (ec == asio::error::eof) { // 'end of file' is fine
                   std::cout << "receiveResponse(): close_notify received" << std::endl;
                   shutdown();
               }
           });
       }

       void shutdown() {
           m_socket.async_shutdown([/*this*/](error_code ec) {
               if (ec) {
                   std::cout << "shutdown() failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
               }
           });
       }

       bool verifyCertificate(bool preverified, ssl::verify_context& ctx) {
           char  subject_name[256];
           X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
           X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);

           std::cout << "certificate " << (preverified ? "valid" : "invalid") << ": " << subject_name
                     << std::endl;
           return preverified;
       }

     private:
       std::deque<std::string_view> m_requests{"authentication request", "application query"};
       ssl::stream<tcp::socket>     m_socket;
       std::string                  m_buffer;
   };

   int main() {
       try {
           asio::io_context ioc;
           auto             endpoint = tcp::resolver(ioc).resolve("127.0.0.5", "2405");

           ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv13_client);
           ctx.load_verify_file("rootCA_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_certificate_chain_file("client_cert.pem");
           ctx.use_private_key_file("client_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);

           TlsClient client(ioc.get_executor(), ctx, endpoint);
           ioc.run();
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
       }

       std::cout << "\nEND" << std::endl;
   }
  ```

And it works as I'd hope:

[image]

### Sidenote

Of course if you write the server in async fashion, it wouldn't really matter in which order you initiate the write/read because they may overlap (although you may not overlap reads or writes *among themselves*). I haven't seen your async server code, so I cannot comment further on why you claimed *"The problem also occurs with an asynchronous boost/asio implementation."*

Comment: Thank you for your efforts sehe. I really appreciate it. Your solution already improves the situation :)
But the core of the problem is still there, because here the server sends the response first and then authenticates the client. So it should be the other way around. I found a workaround for myself, which I'll write about in my first post.   ...it does not solve the problem described about post-handshake authentication, but I can get further.

Comment: small remark about "asynchronous boost/asio": I originally had the asynchronous approach in (async_handshake, async_read, ...). It hadn't worked there and I hoped it would with the synchronous/succesive approach. ..but nah  :)

Comment: Yeah I'm intrigued by those issues. Out of curiosity I made an async server myself here, and it seems to work fine, including handling several requests with responses before authentication, and even dealing with repeated auth requests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332104/85371

Comment: Better attempt that actually ensures the order, at the expense of extending application protocol https://stackoverflow.com/a/77333090/85371