Boost Beast Websocket verify client certificate more than once on connection
I have a Boost Beast asio based websocket server, which (in abbreviated form) starts like this
ssl_context_.set_options(
    boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
    boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2            |
    boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3            |
    boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1            |
    boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1_1
    );

ssl_context_.use_certificate_file(
    auth->server_cert,
    boost::asio::ssl::context::file_format::pem
    );

ssl_context_.use_private_key_file(
    auth->server_key,
    boost::asio::ssl::context::file_format::pem
    );

ssl_context_.load_verify_file(auth->ca);

ssl_context_.set_verify_mode(
    boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer |
    boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert
    );

ssl_context_.set_verify_callback(
    std::bind(
      &verify_certificate_cb, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2
      )
    );
    
try
{
  const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(ip), port);
  acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
  acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
  acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
  acceptor_.listen();
}
catch(const boost::system::system_error &e)
{
  LOG_ERROR("Acceptor error: " << e.what());
  return;
}
 
acceptor_.async_accept(io_context_, boost::beast::bind_front_handler(&server::accept_handler, this));

and then, I have
static bool verify_certificate_cb(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
{
  char subject_name[256];
  X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
  X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
  LOG_INFO("TLS connection verification for: " << subject_name);
  return preverified;
}

void server::accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) noexcept
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Using Boost's asio paradigm, websocket binds its completion handlers to a shared ptr of this object.
    // This allows the object to extend its lifetime beyond this scope until it's operations are done.
    // Once the all async operations are done, no reference remains, finally ending the lifetime of this object.
    const auto ws(std::make_shared<websocket>(std::move(socket), ssl_context_, auth_));
    
    // Initiate websocket handshake
    ws->handshake();

    // Continue with accepting the next available connection
    acceptor_.async_accept(io_context_, boost::beast::bind_front_handler(&server::accept_handler, this));
  }
  else
  {
    LOG_ERROR("Acceptor error: " << error.message());
  }
}

This works great for validating client certificates on initial connection. The problem is that this websocket server expects clients to be connected for a long time, possibly longer than the validity of the client certificate. In other words, I need to periodically re-check the client certificate after the initial connection is made. What is the best way to do that?
UPDATE 1: post @sehe comment
I agree my question seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327517/4071435. I switched from ssl_context_.set_verify_mode() to SSL_CTX_set_verify() because the former does not support SSL_VERIFY_POST_HANDSHAKE. Then, in my downstream websocket async write handler (just a convenient place), I added SSL_verify_client_post_handshake(websocket_.next_layer().native_handle()); but that always returns 0, which is a failure. So, I seem to be missing something.
My test client is a python3-websockets based application
import websocket, ssl
import time

my_context = ssl.create_default_context()
my_context.load_verify_locations('/usr/share/www/daikin-txrx-ws/public_html/daikin-txrx-ws-ca.crt')
my_context.load_cert_chain(
        '/usr/share/www/daikin-txrx-ws/public_html/daikin-txrx-ws-client.crt',
        '/usr/share/www/daikin-txrx-ws/public_html/daikin-txrx-ws-client.key')
my_context.check_hostname = False
my_context.post_handshake_auth = True
my_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED

ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={'context': my_context})
ws.connect('wss://localhost:889');

while True:
    ws.send("Hello, Server")
    print(ws.recv())
    time.sleep(1)

What else am I missing?
UPDATE 2: Better, but still missing something.
The problem with update1 above stemmed from the fact that SSL_verify_client_post_handshake() is a TLSv1.3 feature. The reason the code seems to not work is because openssl s_client and pythons-websocket both connect with TLSv1.2. When I add -tls1_3 to openssl s_client to force TLSv1.3, boost beast websocket rejects the connection with unsupported protocol.
This led me to find (an obvious in hindsight) problem. I had initialized my ssl_context with boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12. I changed it to boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv13 and both clients were able to connect with TLSv1.3!
This also changed the behavior of SSL_verify_client_post_handshake(). The first invocation now returns 1 (YAY!!!), but the next invocation, about 1 second later returns 0. Seems like I'm very close now, but still missing something ...
UPDATE 3: It works!
Actually, update 2 was working. The second call to SSL_verify_client_post_handshake() returning 0 is just an indication that the previous request wasn't yet completed.

this seems related (post-handshakes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77303111/tlsv1-3-post-handshake-server-only-verifies-the-client-certificate-when-the-con/77333090#77333090

I would probably just choose to reconnect every once in a while. Network connections aren't 100% reliable anyways, so you need quick reconnect logic anyways. Simple is most often best.

@sehe - I updated my question with what I think you were suggesting in regard to TLS post-handshake certificate verification, but it seems to be not working. Can you please take a look?

Are you sure you need to from a security standpoint? The client certificate authenticates the client at the time of the connection. Just because the certificate expired does not mean the authentication decision was incorrect when it was made. Even if the certificate was revoked because the client leaked their private key does not mean the existing, long-lived connection is compromised. It means future connections should be rejected, which they will be.

@sehe - I think I've tracked down the problem. SSL_verify_client_post_handshake() is a TLSv1.3 feature. The reason the code seems to not work is because openssl s_client and pythons-websocket both connect with TLSv1.2. When I add  -tls1_3 to openssl s_client to force TLSv1.3, boost beast websocket rejects the connection with unsupported protocol. I'm stuck at this now. From what I can tell, I did not do anything to inhibit TLSv1.3 for boost beast. Any thoughts?

To verify the client certificate more than once on a connection, you can implement a custom verification callback that checks the certificate at each handshake. Make sure to handle the state of the connection properly to avoid issues.

Recommend a bit more meat here, particularly showing how to mitigate the problems raised in the last sentence.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
