# SSL shutdown with check for error code and consideration of pending data

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I would like to ensure a proper shutdown of an SSL connection. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22575315/1460794) I found a code snippet to distinguish a graceful shutdown from a short read error:

```
// const boost::system::error_code &ec
if (ec.category() == asio::error::get_ssl_category() &&
  ec.value() == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ)) {
  // -> not a real error, just a normal TLS shutdown
}
```

The code above makes sense in light of the following code in [`engine.ipp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp):

```
const boost::system::error_code& engine::map_error_code(
    boost::system::error_code& ec) const
{
  // We only want to map the error::eof code.
  if (ec != boost::asio::error::eof)
    return ec;

  // If there's data yet to be read, it's an error.
  if (BIO_wpending(ext_bio_))
  {
    ec = boost::system::error_code(
        ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ),
        boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
    return ec;
  }

  // SSL v2 doesn't provide a protocol-level shutdown, so an eof on the
  // underlying transport is passed through.
  if (ssl_->version == SSL2_VERSION)
    return ec;

  // Otherwise, the peer should have negotiated a proper shutdown.
  if ((::SSL_get_shutdown(ssl_) & SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN) == 0)
  {
    ec = boost::system::error_code(
        ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ),
        boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
  }

  return ec;
}
```

In the code above the error is remapped, which I then check for specifically. But after reading the function above I don't feel reassured.

It seems that both:

- `if (BIO_wpending(ext_bio_))` (data to be read), and
- `if ((::SSL_get_shutdown(ssl_) & SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN) == 0)` (negotiated proper shutdown)

will generate the same error that I'm checking for.

Will my error check miss an error if `(BIO_wpending(ext_bio_))` is true? I don't know what exactly this check is looking at. Does it matter?

Comment: This answer gives a good description of [asio SSL behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error/25703699#25703699). Also see this question: [proper way to disconnect an SSLsocket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046034/what-is-the-proper-way-to-securely-disconnect-an-asio-ssl-socket) since the behaviour may have changed...